# does android-wheel work on Samsung Galaxy S2 ICS update

Tags: android, android-widget, samsung-mobile

I've implemented the [android-wheel](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) widget in one of my projects recently in place of spinners and time/date pickers. There is a [reported bug](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/issues/detail?id=36) that only affects Samsung Galaxy S2 phones with the new ICS update here. This seems to be a bit of a deal breaker as this is such a phenomenally popular phone. Can anyone with a Galaxy S2 confirm this is the case by [downloading](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/downloads/list) the demo app and testing? Or shed any light about why it doesn't work on this particular phone only?

Comment: We've had many issues come up with just ICS on that device. Don't know if this will help but check out Samsung's dev help here: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=10624&listReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Finnovator.samsungmobile.com%3A80%2Fplatform.main.do%3FplatformId%3D1&linkType=0&nacode=&codeType=C514 http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=11184&linkType=0&nacode=uk&sortType=0&codeType=All

Answer (score 0):

Here's my fix:
In WheelView class
in `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method move

```
if (getParent() != null) {
    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
}
```

from switch to the beginning of the method